# Замена матвьюх средствами sqlalchemy

Tags: python, база-данных, orm, sqlalchemy

Добрый день.

Есть проект с приличной историей, за время существования которого в базе накопилось много монструозных вьюх, в которые вынесен значительный кусок бизнес-логики.

Результаты выполнения вьюх в итоге приходят в питон, поэтому есть мысль вообще заменить вьюхи питоновским кодом на основе sqlalchemy.

Проблема в том, что некоторые из этих вьюх - материализованные. Запросы в них очень тяжёлые и просто перенести их логику на "алхимию" - не вариант.

Можно ли здесь придумать что-нибудь не очень костыльное?

UPD: Речь идёт об Oracle.

Comment: СУБД укажите на всякий случай.

Comment: @Dmitry, Oracle, добавил в вопрос.

Comment: А в чем проблема с матвью? Я с ними не работал (как-то не довелось), но, теоретически, основным проблемы у вас должны быть с обычными вьюхами, и их стоит переделать на материализованные.

Comment: @Dmitry, обычная вьюха - это по сути просто запрос select, который понятно как заменить средствами sqlalchemy. Но материализованная вьюха - это тяжёлый запрос, который средствами БД предварительно вычисляется по определённому расписанию, что позволяет не тратить время на его вычисление, когда он понадобится. Как это заменить "алхимией" и при этом не городить костыли с системой скриптов, запускаемых по расписанию?

Comment: Я старый солдат и не знаю слов любви (с). Как базовик-затейник со стажем, я вообще не стал бы ничего заменять "алхимией". У оракловых матвью есть фишка обновляться, как только обновятся исходные данные, т. е. оно всегда будет в актуальном состоянии. Но я, повторюсь, теоретик. Там много всяких нюансов, попробуйте копнуть глубже: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6002.htm#i2064161